# Load image from firebase database to cell imageview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to swift so am still following tutorials to learn how things work but things are not really working out for me like in the tutorial. Am trying to load image from firebase database into cell imageview like this

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    let userr = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = userr.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = userr.email
    
    
    if let profileImageUrl = userr.image_url {
        let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

but it's not working, Both name and email both loads successful but image don't  and i don't know where i am getting it wrong.

Comment: Did you get any error print log from ``` print(error)```???

Comment: Do not load images uncached in `cellForRow`. This is pretty inefficient. There are libraries like [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to do this independently.

Comment: no error printed. i added a break point on `                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)` and it appears to be successful

Comment: Most likely the `dataTask(with:, completionHandler:)` is an asynchronous operation, and the `return cell` in your code runs before the `completionHandler` is ever executed. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+asynchronous